# mat-table does not render my Observable<any[]> when using mergeMap

Tags: angular, angular-material, observable, rxjs6

Posted nice example on stackBlitz :-)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f351cx

I am having some troubles combining two database lookups in firebase into a single observable that renders nicely into my mat-table.

I made it pretty far. I can get ONE database lookup to display in a table by just returning the observable, but once I try to connect the second, nothing shows in the table.

I find this very strange, cause when I async/JSON pipe the result of my second Observable the result seems to have the right format.

What am I doing wrong? My example uses http.get() and restcountries.eu, but I am actually trying to make it work with Firebase. The error/behaviour is the same though, both at my own application and in this example.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like when you call `return of(myArray)` the observable finishes before you get the value from the second http request.

If you add `.pipe(delay(100));` to it, the value in the table is shown.

Code will then be:

```
this.singleObsDataSource = this.http.get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/regionalbloc/efta')
this.doubleObsDataSource = this.singleObsDataSource.pipe(mergeMap((data: any[]) => {
  let myArray = [];
  data.forEach(country => {
    let url = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/' + country['name'];
    this.http.get(url).subscribe(countryInfo=>{
      myArray.push(countryInfo[0]);
    })
  })
  return of(myArray).pipe(delay(100));
}))
```

[Working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7xc7ts?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Well, it works. So I will give you an upvote. However....what will happen when resolving request takes 101milliseconds? This solution is not super permanent...but like I said....well worth an upvote.

Comment: Question: would this work? [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f351cx)

Comment: Im not sure what that last link was supposed to lead to, seems to be the same as link as in the original question, and also your "working stackblitz" link is leading to a non working stackblitz.
Anyways, I found a good workaround for the problem that could happen if the second observable doesn't resolve itself before the 100ms in your example.
I just wrapped it in a loop that checks if the data returned is valid, and then doubles the delay up to a max timeout value if its not resolved. I feel like there is a better solution out there, but it will do for now